# Why is my stored MySQL procedure so slow?

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, pagespeed

I have made a procedure which runs two queries: one for credit amount and a second for debit amount and return outstanding.

I have made a procedure for these queries. It returns me the same result but takes five times longer than simple queries.

Why does the procedure takes more time? I have read that procedures are faster then simple queries.

My simple php method

```
function getOutStandingBalance($OID)
{
    $strSQL  = "select sum(amount) from t where isdeleted=0 and iscredit=1 and oid='1212'";
    $Result1 = $this->ADb->ExecuteQuery($strSQL);

    $CreditSum = $Result1->fields[0];

    $strSQL  = "select sum(amount) from t where isdeleted=0 and iscredit=0 and oid='1212'";     $Result2 = $this->ADb->ExecuteQuery($strSQL);

    $DebitSum = $Result2->fields[0];

    $OutStandingBalance = sprintf("%2.2f",$CreditSum - $DebitSum);
    echo $OutStandingBalance;
}
```

My Procedure

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `getOutStandingBalance`(OUT Total DECIMAL(16,2),IN OID INT)
    DETERMINISTIC
    COMMENT 'A procedure'
BEGIN
    DECLARE Credit DECIMAL(16,2);
    DECLARE Debit  DECIMAL(16,2);
    SELECT SUM(t.Amount) INTO Credit FROM `t` WHERE t.IsDeleted=0 AND t.IsCredit=1 AND t.OID=OID;

    SELECT SUM(t.Amount) INTO Debit FROM `t` WHERE t.IsDeleted=0 AND t.IsCredit=0 AND t.OID=OID;

    SET Total = IFNULL(Credit, 0) - IFNULL(Debit, 0);
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

PHP Script With Procedure call and simple php queries call with benchmarking

```
$begin = microtime(true);
$chkAmount      = $myTransaction->getOutStandingBalance(1212);
echo $chkAmount;
echo "<br />";
$end = microtime(true); 
echo "Time taken for normal:", $end - $begin;
$norml = $end - $begin;
echo "<br />";
echo "<br />";
$begin = microtime(true);
$stmt = "CALL getOutStandingBalance(@Total,1212)";
$rsstmt = "SELECT @Total;";
$rs = $myADb->Execute($stmt);
$rsstmt = $myADb->Execute($rsstmt);
echo $rsstmt->fields[0];
echo "<br />";
$end = microtime(true); 
echo "Time taken for Procedure:", $end - $begin; 

$procd = $end - $begin;

if($norml>$procd)
{
    echo "<br> Procedure is Fast.";
}
else
{
    echo "<br> Normal Query is Fast.";
}
```

Comment: Perhaps the values are being summed as Decimal when before they were floats or some other type.

Comment: Is the extra time taken by your procedure consistent and repeatable, even when you try it over multiple different values of OID? How much longer does the procedure take?  Have you considered that hitting the same rows over and over measures the row-caching efficiency of MySQL more than it does the querying efficiency?